# Can real particles be created from a false vacuum spontaneously through decay?

Tags: cosmology, universe, vacuum, phase-transition, bubbles

Consider false vacuum decay.

Given the **energy difference** between the false to true,

Can this process lead to the creation of **real** particles as well as the vacuum bubbles?

Comment: Great comment, thanks, Schwinger effect can be thought of as "vacuum decay" in the presence of an electric field", but this question is in the absence of it.

Comment: Related: [How is mass-energy conserved during false vacuum decay?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/522632/)